# Can I put each s3 object into its own prefix to maximize throughput

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

S3's throughput limits are per-prefix, not per-object:

> your application can achieve at least 3,500 PUT/COPY/POST/DELETE or 5,500 GET/HEAD requests per second per prefix in a bucket
> [AWS Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/optimizing-performance.html)

It seems to follow that if I place each of my s3 objects in a prefix (by itself), I'll effectively be able to have the above throughput per-object.

However I'm a bit suspicious of this conclusion. If it is true, why would someone consider [s3 write sharding](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-object-key-naming-pattern/) which is a bit more complicated?

To clarify, what I'm considering is whenever I'm about to save an object in s3 (eg. `foo/bar/baz.txt`), I save add a *folder* so that the file has its own prefix (eg. `foo/bar/baz.txt/baz.txt`). Now I can have 5500 reads per second on the object `baz.txt` (without the prefix, those 5500 reads per second would be shared across all objects in `foo/bar/`).

Comment: I think you have wrong link to "s3 write sharding"?

Comment: Is there a particular problem you are trying to solve? Are you experiencing any problems with current throughput?

Comment: @Marcin, I double checked. Looks correct to me? Putting files in multiple prefixes to increase throughput.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein, yes, I observed 503 slow down errors. One of the suggested solutions is exponential backoff. Another is to use prefixes to spread out the traffic. The latter led me down this idea.

Comment: I know that prefixes are correct, but and what you propose should. Each prefix will get 3500/5000 requests.